# Оптимизировать функцию

Tags: php, массивы, алгоритм

Выполняю код

```
<?php
$arr = file('arr.txt');
$sum = 0;

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            $sum = array_sum(array_slice($arr,$key,30));
            if($sum > 50) {
                echo $key . ' ' . $sum . "<br>";
            }
        }
?>
```

То есть, поясняю:

```
Суммирую по порядку диапазоны: 
Сумма значений с 0 по 30
Сумма значений с 1 по 31
Сумма значений с 2 по 32
Сумма значений с 3 по 33
Сумма значений с 4 по 34
..
И так до конца.
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 180 seconds exceeded in E:\OSPanel\domains\arr\index.php on line 6
```

Файл arr.txt - это 200к целых чисел (0-100 примерно)

можно оптимизировать, ускорить функцию?
Желательно без усложнений кода - итак с головы выпадает всё. 
если нельзя - как дать время на выполнение?

Comment: а что здесь происходит то вообще, по русски напишите.

Comment: Никогда не ищите текст ошибки в гугле, а то еще найдете ответ и не сможете написать очередной вопрос на SO.

Comment: @u_mulder как оптимизировать код тоже не искать?

Comment: @u_mulder ответом на вопрос по этой ошибке будет отключение таймлимита например, хотя тут можно улучшить алгоритм, ибо слайсы постоянно выделяют память, а суммировнаие массива нафиг не нужно, кроме первого. затем только +конец -начало делать.
То есть тут помимо проблемы с лимитом еще и алгоритм не оптимален. хотя и понятен

Comment: тут банальное `function rangeSum($arr, $start, $len = 30){ $sum = 0; while($len--) $sum+=$arr[$start++]; return $sum; }` может дать небольшой прирост производительности за счет исключения 200тыс слайсов массива (проверку на конец надо правда еще)

Comment: @teran написал по русски что происходит

Comment: вы поставьте курсор массива на 30ю позицию. Посчитайте сумму первую. Дальше итератором крутите его до конца прибавляя `current()` и отнимая `$arr[key($arr) - 29]`. Не надо для этих вычислений отрезать всегда часть массива и целиком ее считать. у вас сумма меняется только на 2 элемента на концах.

Comment: о как, интересно, спасибо

Comment: можете в принципе это сделать читая файл построчно. тогда вообще не придется память на эти 200к строк выделять, и фактически время выполнения будет равно времени чтения. И если уже его не хватит, то просто отключите таймлимит на выполнение скрипта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем говоря, при наличии достаточно большого файла, каким бы оптимальным ни был алгоритм, вы все равно будете упираться в таймлимит, Для заведомо больших задач его отключают.

Давайте посмотрим, что и как влияет на производительность. Я сгенерировал массив из 200к значений и записал его в файл. На момент конца генерации объем использованной памяти (`memory_get_usage()`) составил 29 Мбайт.
Далее я отключил тайм лимит (`set_time_limit(0)`) и запустил ваш скрипт, дабы проверить, сколько же он будет выполняться, и завершился тон через 770 секунд.

Предполагаем, что основная причина долгой обработки в том, что 200к раз выполняется slice (долгий не сам по себе слайс, а вероятно то, что менеджер памяти постоянно что-то выделяет, а коллектор уничтожает). Если заменить `array_sum(array_slice( ... ))` на функцию, считающую сумму элементов вручную

```
$rangeSum = function($data, $s) use ($count){
    $sum = 0;
    $end = min($s+30, $count);
    while($s < $end){
         $sum += $data[$s++];
    }
    return $sum;
};
```

время работы - 1.4 секунды.

Следующий вариант - посчитать сумму первых 30 элементов. А дальше двигаться по массиву. Вычесть первый, добавить следующий:

```
$i = 0;
while($i < 30) $sum += $arr[$i++];
$x = $sum > 50 ? 1 : 0;

for($i = 30; $i < $count; $i++){<-->
    $sum += -$arr[$i-30] + $arr[$i];
    if($sum > 50) $x++;
}
```

Тут я немного пренебрег концом массива, и фактически последние 30 сумм не считает, но  результат - 0.25 сек.

Есть еще вариант - читать файл построчно. Но т.к. вам потребуется хранить текущие 30 элементов в массиве и каждый раз делать shift/push (чтобы хранить этот -30 элемент), то его производительность будет ниже ~0.35сек, зато вы всегда храните только 30 значений, а не 200тыс, поэтому потребление памяти будет минимально.

```
while( ($v = fgets($f)) !== false){
    $m = array_shift($values);
    $sum += -$m + $v;
    $values[] = $v;

    if($sum > 50) $x++;
}
```

предварительно мы тут уже считали первые 30 строк и просуммировали.

*зы: весь приведенный код вырван из контекста и не полон, просто для передачи смысла*

Comment: еще учтите, что если у вас числа от 0 до 100, и вы считаете сумму 30 таких значений, то она почти постоянно будет больше 50. в моем случае с поомщью rand генерировались числа от 0 до 30, и в 199998 случаях сумма была больше. Так что если вы выводите на экран ключи и сумму, то готовьтесь с небольшой задержкой получить мегабайт 30 текста в ответ

Comment: Числа в основном не большие в массиве

Comment: Взял второй вариант (+ след., - пред. элемент)

Answer (score -1):

Ну, если ничего не перепутал, то можно так -

```
<?php
$arr = file('arr.txt');
$sum = array_sum(array_slice($arr,0,30));
for($i = 1; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
    if($sum > 50) {
       echo ($i-1) . ' ' . $sum . "<br>";
    }
    $sum = $sum + $arr[$i] - $arr[$i-1] ;
}
?>
```